# Implementing Central Symmetry

Tags: computational-geometry, symmetry

I'm interested in implementing symmetry groups.  So it would be useful to have central symmetry (isometry transformation). There are built-in functions: `RotationTransform`, `TranslationTransform` and `ReflectionTransform`, but I was not able to find something like central symmetry. The goal is to translate one object of any kind (image or built-in graphical primitives) into the symmetric analog to it.

If anyone has any thoughts, please write!

Comment: By central symmetry, do you mean [point reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection)?  If that is the case, you can use `ScalingTransform[{-1,-1,-1},{p1,p2,p3}]`.  This will reflect your graphics object about the point $(p1,p2,p3)$.  I assume you plan to use it for 3-dimensional graphics object.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya That sounds like the correct interpretation; you should go ahead and turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Point reflection in dimension 2 coincides with a half-turn, so `RotationTransform` suffices in that case.

```
In[1]:= TransformationMatrix@ScalingTransform[{-1,-1},{p1,p2}]
Out[1]= {{-1,0,2 p1},{0,-1,2 p2},{0,0,1}}
In[2]:= TransformationMatrix@RotationTransform[Pi,{p1,p2}]
Out[2]= {{-1,0,2 p1},{0,-1,2 p2},{0,0,1}}
```

In dimension 3, point reflection is an orientation-reversing isometry, so it no longer coincides with `RotationTransform`.  However, it is still an isometry generated by reflections.  So strictly speaking, we can obtain point reflection by composing `ReflectionTransform` along three mutually-orthogonal vectors.  Nevertheless, it is more convenient to use `ScalingTransform` instead.

The following example is adapted from the documentation for `ReflectionTransform`:

```
In[3]:= cow=ExampleData[{"Geometry3D","Cow"},"GraphicsComplex"];
In[4]:= Graphics3D[{
          EdgeForm[None],Opacity[0.5],Lighter[ColorData[1,1],0.5],
          cow
         },Boxed->False]
```

[image: Original cow]

Now we apply our point reflection to the cow about the origin:

```
In[5]:= Graphics3D[{
          EdgeForm[None],Opacity[0.5],Lighter[ColorData[1,1],0.5],
          GeometricTransformation[cow,ScalingTransform[{-1,-1,-1},{0,0,0}]]
         },Boxed->False]
```

[image: Point-reflected cow]

If you are interested in isometries in dimensions higher than 3, then things get more complicated.  The isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the semi-direct product of translations and isometries fixing the origin, so we need only understand the latter (the orthogonal group $O(n)$).  The good news is that by the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem, every element of $O(n)$ is a composition of at most $n$ reflections, so there is no need to implement a new geometric transformation.  However, see the MathOverflow [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37136) for more information about challenges in enumerating even finite subgroups of isometries in dimensions $n\geq5$.

Comment: Szabolcs' image uploader came in handy.